# Android studio some properties are missing

Tags: android, android-studio

hi I'm new to android studio. While I was working I realized some of the properties in the attributes panel are missing. For example for plain text the hint property was missing, for buttons the onClick property was missing...The only way I could advance was to just hardcode those values. Is there any solution for this? appreciate for the response

Comment: clean the project

Comment: I tried but still didn't worked.Its happening in new projects as well

Comment: did you try invalidate caches and restart